# Hyphens between buttons when commenting out white space

Tags: html, css

When I try to remove gaps between my buttons by commenting out the white space between them, these little black dashes appear instead, which are selectable using the tab button. I can make them non visable with `text-decoration: false` and I can remove the gap with `margin-left: -4px` but whatever it is is still there and is selected when using the tab button.

Why are these dashes there and how do I get rid of them?

**HTML:**

```
<a target="_blank" a href= "https://Google.com">
<button class="button">
<strong>LinkedIn</strong><br>
</button></a><!--
--><a target="_blank" a href= "https://www.Google.com">
<button class="button">
<strong>GitHub</strong><br>
</button></a>
<br><!--
--><a target="_blank" a href= "https://www.Google.com">
<button class="button">
<strong>Stack Overflow</strong><br>
</button></a><!--
--><a target="_blank" a href= "https://www.Google.com">
<button class="button">
<strong>HackerRank</strong><br>
</button></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    height: 623px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;    
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
}

.button{
    background-color: rgb(224,184,219);
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 100px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(224,184,219);
    outline: none;
}
:focus, :visited{
    border: 2px solid rgb(153,217,234);
    outline: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/mpbev9ay/1/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put `<button>` elements in `<a>` elements. They're both interactive controls and as such it's forbidden to nest them inside one another.

The [W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-a-element.html) defines `<a>`'s content model (i.e. what it can have inside) as

> Transparent, but there must be no [interactive content](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/content-models.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

where

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>
> a, audio (if the controls attribute is present), ***button***, details, embed, iframe, img (if the usemap attribute is present), input (if the type attribute is not in the Hidden state), keygen, label, menu (if the type attribute is in the toolbar state), object (if the usemap attribute is present), select, textarea, video (if the controls attribute is present)

(emphasis mine)

So the solution is to rearrange your HTML so that that no longer happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a browser inspector, like in Chrome, you can use the process of elimination to figure out where the line is coming from. From what I can tell, it's the newline that is within the `a` element but before the `button` element.

Some suggestions:

- Comment out all the new lines/white-space, not just the few you already did
- Use `text-decoration: none;` on the `a` element instead of the `button` element
- Use `font-size: 0;` on the `a` element then `font-size: 1rem;` on the `button`

Answer (score -1):

You also need to comment out the white space between `<a>` and `<button>`, see below.

```css
div{
display: inline-block;
white-space: normal;
height: 623px;
padding: 10px;
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 0; 
vertical-align: top;
border-bottom: 3px solid black;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
}

.button{
background-color: rgb(224,184,219);
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
width: 160px;
height: 100px;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
}
.button:hover{
background-color: white;
color: rgb(224,184,219);
outline: none;
}
:focus, :visited{
border: 2px solid rgb(153,217,234);
outline: none;
outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href= "https://Google.com"><!--
--><button class="button">
<strong>LinkedIn</strong><br>
</button></a><!--
--><a target="_blank"  href= "https://www.Google.com"><!--
--><button class="button">
<strong>GitHub</strong><br>
</button></a>
<br><!--
--><a target="_blank"  href= "https://www.Google.com"><!--
--><button class="button">
<strong>Stack Overflow</strong><br>
</button></a><!--
--><a target="_blank"  href= "https://www.Google.com"><!--
--><button class="button">
<strong>HackerRank</strong><br>
</button></a>
```

OR you can use `onclick` on `<button>`, as below

```css
div{
display: inline-block;
white-space: normal;
height: 623px;
padding: 10px;
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 0; 
vertical-align: top;
border-bottom: 3px solid black;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
}

.button{
background-color: rgb(224,184,219);
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 10px;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
width: 160px;
height: 100px;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
}
.button:hover{
background-color: white;
color: rgb(224,184,219);
outline: none;
}
:focus, :visited{
border: 2px solid rgb(153,217,234);
outline: none;
outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="window.open('https://Google.com','_blank')">
<strong>LinkedIn</strong><br></button><!--
--><button class="button" onclick="window.open('https://Google.com','_blank')">
<strong>GitHub</strong><br>
</button><br><!--
--><button class="button" onclick="window.open('https://Google.com','_blank')">
<strong>Stack Overflow</strong><br>
</button><!--
--><button class="button" onclick="window.open('https://Google.com','_blank')">
<strong>HackerRank</strong><br>
</button>
```